# Can't scrape Text files that are dynamically loaded

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to collect data from the USDA specifically https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/2960 and I collect all recent data from sept 14 to july of 2020. It seems like they have switched they way they stored data so from july of 2020 to october of 2017 they are stored as text files which I want to mine but I cannot find a reliable way to do so.

I have tried multiple methods, as of right now something was wrong with my selenium import which didn't let me use Chromedriver which maybe could solve my issue

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = 'https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/viewReport/2960'

def extract_text_file_links(driver):
    # Modify the selector as necessary
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href$=".txt"]')
    return [element.get_attribute('href') for element in elements]

def main():
    # Set up the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True  # This runs Chrome in the background
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='changed path', options=options)

    try:
        driver.get(URL)
    
        # Waiting for a specific element to ensure the page has loaded.
        # Adjust the selector and timeout as necessary.
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href$=".txt"]')))
    
        text_file_links = extract_text_file_links(driver)
        for link in text_file_links:
            print(link)
        # You can then download these files as demonstrated in previous answers.

    finally:
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x0000020075CC4820>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

No matter what I can't get this scarper to work the files are in a folder on the website and I don't know how to properly scrape things like that

Comment: I don't think web scraping is necessary here. It looks like there's already an API to get the data you want: https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/public_data?slug_id=2960

Comment: I was able to get the data from present to around july of 2020. It seems like they changed they way they made reports around then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirements correctly, the following piece of code should help you get the expected text files from that webpage:

```
import requests

base = 'https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov{}'
link = 'https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/get_previous_release/2960'

params = {
    'type': 'month',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    for year in ['2017','2018','2019','2020']:
        for month in range(1,13):
            params['month'] = month
            params['year'] = int(year)
            resp = s.get(link,params=params)
            if not resp.json()['data']: continue
            for item in resp.json()['data']:
                if item['file_extension']!='TXT': continue
                print(base.format(item['document_url']))
```

Output (truncated):

```
https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2017-10-31/476944/LR_GR11120171031.TXT
https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2017-10-27/476943/LR_GR11120171027.TXT
https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2017-10-26/476942/LR_GR11120171026.TXT
https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2017-10-25/476941/LR_GR11120171025.TXT
```

Comment: sorry new to actually posting I accepted it thank you again

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Network Tab, they download the links you see on the page via Javascript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it.

You can use this example how to get the PDF link:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/get_latest_release/2960"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).json()["html"], "html.parser")

f = "https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov" + soup.select_one('a[href$="pdf"]')["href"]
print(f)
```

Prints:

```
https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2023-09-15/749643/ams_2960_00836.pdf
```

Comment: I was able to do something similar to this but I need it to loop and capture all the TXT files not just the latest release

Comment: @ConorLarkin I don't see the .txt link on that URL

Comment: /filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2020-06-29/293115/ams_2960_00086.txt

all the files from 2017 to july 2020 are txt files that I have been trying to mine

https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/filerepo/sites/default/files/2960/2020-06-29/293115/ams_2960_00086.txt